# how do import the Skype object using react js?

Tags: reactjs, skype

could anyone help me out here?  Just trying to embed a simple Skype button in my react app, but due to my apparent lack of understanding of modules, imports, webpack, and how create-react-app actually does what it does, I can't access the Skype object.  It's not defined.

I have followed instructions

```
https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/
```

I have linked to the skype js using a script tag in my index.html's          `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>`

inside my main js file, using create-react-app:

```
loadSkype() {
        Skype.ui({
          "name": "dropdown",
          "element": "SkypeButton_Call_john23",
          "participants": ["john23"],
          "imageSize": 32
          })
      }
```

I can not access the `Skype` object.  Any ideas?

The instructions make it sound really simple: copy and paste the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_john23_1">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 Skype.ui({
 "name": "call",
 "element": "SkypeButton_Call_john23_1",
 "participants": ["john23"]
 });
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you also add the div with the id `<div id="SkypeButton_Call_john23">` on your code?

Comment: yes i did but it doesn't work still

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/nrv05pxk4j

Comment: fabio i am happy to give you 500 points if you want it, but apparently your reply needs to be an actual answer, not a comment

Comment: where and how do you call `loadSkype()` ?

Comment: `The instructions make it sound really simple`. Pls share your reference link.

Comment: yes, Fabio's code does work and I have it working, just want to award him some bounty points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `index.html` you need import the skype library:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create a component for skype and import it whenever you want to use it:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

class SkypeBT extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Skype.ui({
      name: "dropdown",
      element: "SkypeButton_Call_john23",
      participants: ["john23"],
      imageSize: 32
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="SkypeButton_Call_john23" />;
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <h2>Call me</h2>
    <SkypeBT />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

You can fid a working version in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nrv05pxk4j)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet creates a button for your website, if you need to create an object then you should create a new div element and set the id to `SkypeButton_Call_john23_1`. Then you need to create a script element and place the json inside it.

```
loadSkype() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'SkypeButton_Call_john23_1';

    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.value =
        Skype.ui({
            "name": "call",
            "element": "SkypeButton_Call_john23_1",
            "participants": ["john23"]
        });

    div.appendChild(s);
    return div;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm on the right track, but i still get Skype is not defined.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Where are you referring to Skype?

Comment: Inside app.js in component did mount i execute the loadSkype() function. In that function is the Skype.ui() function that is not being imported. However this script isn’t a package or anything. Just a script you need to link to.  I have already linked to it using a.src=

Comment: Ah, then the code I provided will not work like that. That function that I have create above returns the button as an object. To use it you just call it in your render {this.loadSkype()}